# Using newer versions of material icons in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

is there a way to use the new version of Material Icons in CodenameOne?

I'm particularly interested in "keyboard_double_arrow_right": https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=keyboard+

Apparently it is no supported in the current version of CodenameOne.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when the font gets out of date we get a community PR to get it to the latest e.g. here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/3259

You can see the discussion around this in the applicable issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3152

Comment: So, I see that the last update was done on 5/11/21 ( https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/3432 ). Unfortunately it doesn't contain the icon I'm looking for.

Comment: Keep an eye on that, it might make it for the next update.